# react native StackOverflowError after updating packages

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

After updating some packages in a react native project I can't run it, a coworker did the updates an it works i any other computer except mine. I've deleted node_modules, yarn.lock, the build carpet of android and cleaned the gradlew. I've even deleted the project entirely and installed from scratch. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

```
CMake Warning at C:/Users/.../Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
    An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
    compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
    values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
    CMake's built-in compiler identification.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/.../Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
    .cxx/Debug/3ay5n6us/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901-dirty/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


  ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 29s

    at makeError (C:\Users\...\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

This is my gradlew configuration

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            //force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
        }

        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```